# How can my result be more exact?

Tags: python, calculator

I have made a little calculator script and when I go to divide and do, let's say 9 / 6. It pops out 1. But I want it to be more exact and pop out 1.5 (The exact result)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

def cls():
    os.system(['clear','cls'][os.name == 'nt'])

cls()
print "Do you want to [1]Add[2]Subtract[3]Multiply[4]Divide?"
k = input("Choose a number next to the choice you want: ")

if (k == 1):
    print "Enter the two numbers you want to add"
    a = input("Number 1: ")
    b = input("Number 2: ")
    cls()
    c = a + b
    print a,"+",b,"=",c
if (k == 2):
    print "Enter the two numbers you want to subtract"
    a = input("Number 1: ")
    b = input("Number 2: ")
    cls()
    c = a - b
    print a,"-",b,"=",c
if (k == 3):
    print "Enter the two numbers you want to multiply"
    a = input("Number 1: ")
    b = input("Number 2: ")
    cls()
    c = a * b
    print a,"*",b,"=",c
if (k == 4):
    print "Enter the two numbers you want to divide"
    a = input("Number 1: ")
    b = input("Number 2: ")
    cls()
    c = a / b
    print a,"/",b,"=",c
```

Comment: try a = float(input("Number 1: ")) etc. to use floating point arithmetic instead of integer arithmetic

Comment: Better just use `from __future__ import division` to get the python3 division semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to be Python 3 compliant. Just use `from __future__ import division` on top and it will behave the same in Python 3.

Other ways include using a dot after a number: `9.0/6` instead of `9/6` or `float(9)/6`.

In Python 3 a normal division `/` will always result in a float, unless you use two slashes: `//`.